# Convert String date to format ISO8601

Tags: python, datetime

I have a date of format : `13 July 2017 22:00` that I would like to convert to an `ISO` date format of type `2017-07-13T22:00:00+0100`.

So far I have managed to do this:

`datetime_object = datetime.strptime(date_start, '%d %B %Y %H:%M')`

where `date_start = '13 July 2017 22:00'`

this returns `2017-07-13 22:00:00` ... close but not the same.

How can I convert it to the type I need ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`datetime.isoformat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat):

```
>>> datetime_object = datetime.strptime('13 July 2017 22:00', '%d %B %Y %H:%M')
>>> datetime_object.isoformat()
'2017-07-13T22:00:00'
```

Note that this produces a timestamp in a "local time zone" (since your initial date has no time zone information attached).